# Cannot close IE with chrome frame

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-frame

I have an interesting issue when using IE and Chrome Frame.

When logging out from my site the url is given an extra '/#/', resulting in 'https://mysite.something.com/something/#/'. This seems to, incredulously enough, hinder IE from closing when pressing the close button.

My site is currently supporting chrome frame and would like to continue doing so. Anyone know of a workaround? Any code on my site that could possibly be relevant?

Please help.

Edit: Tested some more, and logout seems not the issue - manually adding '/#/' also makes me unable to close IE.

Comment: Which server-side framework are you using? ASP.NET MVC?  What code do you use for the log out button?

Comment: Yes, using asp .net 3.5 (might be an mvc 2 proj, not sure). Also using jquery mobile and logging out simply calls $.mobile.changePage(..)

Comment: have your tried `changeHash: false` with `$.mobile.changePage` ?

Comment: I didnt want to remove the hash from other pages, so I ended up just removing it when logging out. But your solution worked well otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the workaround to remove the hash sign when logging out. Not the prettiest but at least IE can now be closed.

```
if (window.externalHost) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
}
```